# Slow, intermittent connection to AD

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins ver. 2.102

I am using the AD security realm.

[image]

There are two issues:

1. The result(success or exception during connection)takes a long time(3-5 minutes) after I click on 'Test Domain'. I did a tail on the /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log but nothing is shown there(do I need to change any logging setting which would NOT overwhelm the log)?
2. I got the AD realm to work. Every time Jenkins is restarted OR a user tries to log-in for the first time, the first log-in takes 3-5 minutes. When this happens, all I can see in the log is:

   Jan 22, 2018 11:47:09 AM hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider resolveGroups
       WARNING: Group lookup via Active Directorys LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN extension matched users groups but took 31 seconds to run. Switching to recursive lookup for future group lookup queries
       Jan 22, 2018 11:47:09 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.Session beginInvalidate
       INFO: Session node014hve5honmguebzkw6acivwbd2 already being invalidated
       Jan 22, 2018 11:47:39 AM hudson.plugins.active_directory.ActiveDirectoryUnixAuthenticationProvider resolveGroups
       WARNING: Group lookup via Active Directorys LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN extension matched users groups but took 32 seconds to run. Switching to recursive lookup for future group lookup queries